# iphone app now is Pending Contract will it be removed from the itunes store?

Tags: ios-appstore, developer-program

I've developed an iPhone app for the company I work for. At the moment there is no need to update or bring out any new apps.
So I thought I could let my apple developer license expire and extend the license when we need it again.

But now I've got a message from apple saying "The status for the following app has changed to Pending Contract." while it was perviously "approved" or something like that.

Is my app gonna be removed from the store with this status?

Comment: The Apple Developer Program is off-topic for this site as per the [FAQ]

Comment: Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different.

Comment: even though apparently this wasn't the place to ask this question, I'm glad I did since I got the answer. but for future questions, where should questions like these be asked?

Comment: Let's leave this here for now. Closed is a fine state that others can still search, learn. It's not clear if SO wants a question like this - so let's move the discussion on where to the meta half of the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this [Apple FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/program-renewals.html) :

> **What happens if I do not renew my iOS Developer Program membership?**
>
> Once your membership expires, **your apps will no longer be available on
>   the App Store** and you will lose the ability to submit new apps. You
>   will lose access to pre-release software, the Apple Developer Forums,
>   Developer Technical Support, and the Certificate Utility. In addition,
>   your existing iOS Distribution certificates will be revoked and
>   invalidated. Finally, if you enrolled in the program as a company, you
>   will lose the ability to manage your development team.
>
> You will, however, retain your status as a Registered Apple Developer
>   and will have access to free development resources.

In order to conserve your app on the AppStore, you must renew your iOS Developer Program.

Hope this helps !